# Resharper output window not showing steps anymore

Tags: resharper, specflow, xunit

Recently we had a change to our Xunit and we upgraded to Xunit 2.0 and all projects to .NET 4.5. Before this change,when I ran the feature file, I remember seeing the steps on the output window (of Resharper unit test session) of a failed test and it would pinpoint where the test failed at. But now, it only shows what kind of error it is and no steps in the output pane. 
Can anyone tell me how to get the steps back as it is very annoying and difficult to find out where the test failed.

Note: We are using specflow to write the tests and run them using Resharper. The version of Resharper I am using is 8.2.1000

Answer (score 0):

Support for XUnit 2.0 does not exist in Specflow yet. There is an [outstanding pull request](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/429), but it still has some issues I think. So I think your options are to revert to the previous version of XUnit or roll up your sleeves and contrbute to the open PR.